# Routing issue in Angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am novice to Angularjs. I was developing small web page. I have login and sign-up form. I have defined login and sign-up `js` code in one main controller. If user is new , I have defined link below the login , on-click of that it should get re-directed to another html page. URl is getting routed, but my `js code`  is not 
responding . I tried to rectify the mistake, but i couldn't achieve it.

Please let me know what mistake, I have done. Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Html code :

```
<form ng-submit="log(userCred)" name="logform" method="get" ng-init="logform = {}"><br/><br>
<div>
    <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="userCred.username" >
</div>

<div >
<label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="userCred.password">
</div>

<div>
    <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" >
</div>
<br/>   
</form>
<div ng-controller="footerctr">
 <p>{{foter}}<a href="home"> Here </a></p>
</div>
```

AngularJS code :

```
var app = angular.module('logapp',['toastr','ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/login',{
    templateUrl : "login.html",
    controller : "credientials"
})      
.when('/home',{
    templateUrl : "home.html",
    controller : "homectrl"
})
.when('/practice',{
    templateUrl : "practice.html",
    controller : "practicectrl"
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);
```

Controller :

```
1. app.controller('credientials',['$scope','$route','$rootScope','$window','$location','$http','toastr','Authentication',function($scope,$route,$rootScope,$window,$location,$http,toastr,Authentication) 

2. app.controller('homectrl',function($scope){});
    app.controller('head',function($scope){
    $scope.hometitle = "Create your account here. It's take only a minute."
});
```

Comment: can you also post controller code?

Comment: @AseemGautam. I have uploaded my controller. please take a look-over

Comment: does the routeProvider work properly? do you reach login/home/practice pages when the route changes?

Comment: @Guy Yogev . Yes my routeProvider is working properly. I can reach to my login/practice page. But I am not able to go for home page..

Comment: Any errors in console? Or path of `home.html` in your project is correct?